# Teradata Database TeraJDBC 16.20.00.04 Error 3610 SQLState HY000 Internal error: Please do not resubmit the last request

Tags: database, jdbc, teradata

Im requesting a report in the form of excel in my application. The application generates a report by running several(31) sql tasks, everytime i submit a request. But for a particular request the execution of 28th task doesnt complete and throws the below error.

**[Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.04] [Error 3610] [SQLState HY000] Internal error: Please do not resubmit the last request.  SubCode, CrashCode:   0,  2693**

```
01/28/2020 10:35:28,586 ERROR com.xxxx.yyyy.zz.Runner:generateBasicReport:174 - java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.04] [Error 3610] [SQLState HY000] Internal error: Please do not resubmit the last request.  SubCode, CrashCode:   0,  2693

com.xxxx.yyyy.zz.exception.ReportGenerationException: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.04] [Error 3610] [SQLState HY000] Internal error: Please do not resubmit the last request.  SubCode, CrashCode:   0,  2693
    at com.xxxx.yyyy.zz.generator.task.CancellableSqlTask.execute(CancellableSqlTask.java:79)
    at com.xxxx.yyyy.zz.generator.task.TaskExecutor.executeNext(TaskExecutor.java:56)
    at com.xxxx.yyyy.zz.generator.ReportGenerator.executeTasks(ReportGenerator.java:119)
    at com.xxxx.yyyy.zz.generator.ReportGenerator.execute(ReportGenerator.java:83)
    at com.xxxx.yyyy.zz.generator.task.CompositeCancellableTask.execute(CompositeCancellableTask.java:32)
    at com.xxxx.yyyy.zz.Runner.executeGeneration(Runner.java:209)
    at com.xxxx.yyyy.zz.Runner.generateBasicReport(Runner.java:171)
    at com.xxxx.yyyy.zz.Runner.generateReports(Runner.java:137)
    at com.xxxx.yyyy.zz.Runner.startReportGenerator(Runner.java:92)
    at com.xxxx.yyyy.zz.Runner.main(Runner.java:69)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.04] [Error 3610] [SQLState HY000] Internal error: Please do not resubmit the last request.  SubCode, CrashCode:   0,  2693
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDatabaseSQLException(ErrorFactory.java:309)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.ReceiveInitSubState.action(ReceiveInitSubState.java:103)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.subStateMachine(StatementReceiveState.java:311)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.action(StatementReceiveState.java:200)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.runBody(StatementController.java:137)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.PreparedStatementController.run(PreparedStatementController.java:46)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeStatement(TDStatement.java:389)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeStatement(TDStatement.java:331)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDPreparedStatement.doPrepExecuteUpdate(TDPreparedStatement.java:225)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(TDPreparedStatement.java:2769)
    at com.xxxx.yyyy.zz.generator.task.CancellableUpdate.perform(CancellableUpdate.java:36)
    at com.xxxx.yyyy.zz.generator.task.CancellableSqlTask.execute(CancellableSqlTask.java:74)
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0):

That means that the request caused some exception that `Teradata` couldn't handle, and like the message says, "don't re-submit".  You could try digging into the logs, but I don't know how fruitful that will be.  I think they are somewhere in `/var/opt/teradata/`.  Otherwise, you'd have to check with customer support to debug.

From the documentation:

```
2693 The fieldids in field 5 are not contiguous.

Explanation: The field descriptors in field 5 should be contiguous, they are not.
Generated By: FldLocat.
For Whom: Site support representative.
Notes: This is caused by an incorrect field 5 header.
Remedy: Contact your Support Representative.
```

Comment: Talk to your DBA to open an incident with Teradata support.